# Lagrangian when ICs are tangent to the budget line

Tags: microeconomics, utility, preferences, lagrangian

Suppose the graph below shows three Indifference Curves such that $t > s > r$, and the budget line $p_1x + p_2y = I$. I was wondering if we set the Lagrangian as $\mathcal{L}= U(x,y) - \lambda (I - p_1x - p_2y)$, do we get all the three tangency points or just the two with greater utility (that is, on $U = s$)?

Since the Lagrangian finds both local maxima and local minima (because it essentially finds saddle points rather than maxima/minima), I feel we will get all three points.

[image]

Comment: You have to check the second order condition using Bordered Hessian, if you want to know which one is maxima or minima.

Comment: @ShaikhAmmar This works only when there's an interior optimum, right? Otherwise, for corner solutions, the maxima may not necessarily correspond to a convex part.

Comment: True, because corner solutions don’t show up in Lagrangian. The only thing Lagrangian does is check if the obj function is tangential to the constraint function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your question: the first order conditions resulting from your Lagrangian are necessary conditions for a local optimum of your optimization problem. You will obtain all candidates for a global maximum.

Comment: Or a local maximum or local minimum

Comment: That's why I wrote "candidates". You still need to check the second order conditions to see whether you are talking about minima, maxima or saddle points.